# How to show numerical UIDs/GIDs stored in tar file

Tags: tar, permissions

I've got some troubles with a tar file that holds a backup. It was provided by our hosting provider and contains some strange file permissions.

When viewing with

```
tar tvf example.tar
```

I only get the symbolic owner information of each file (which do not match existing users in */etc/passwd*). Now I want to investigate whether the numerical values, which should also be stored inside the tar, hold the correct values. Is there a convenient way to do so?

thx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is the `--numeric-owner` switch that gives the information that you want

```
tar --numeric-owner -tvf example.tar
```

> --numeric-owner
>
> ```
>           always use numbers for user/group names
> ```